# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '64-18' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

Tags: magento2

I'm migrating magento 1.9.2 to magento2.0.2..
when I migrating data
(`php bin/magento migrate:data --reset /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/config.xml`)...got the below output...help me if you can..

```
[2017-03-14 01:28:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-03-14 01:28:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-03-14 01:28:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:28:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:29:13][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:29:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:29:33][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-03-14 01:29:33][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
36% [==========>-----------------] Remaining Time: 14 mins

                                                                                                                                      [PDOException]  
                                                                                                                          SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '64-18' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'
```

Comment: Did you get solution for this problem?

Comment: Sort of. I had to empty catalog_product_entity_media_gallary_value table. And migration successful.

Comment: I truncate catalog_product_entity_media_gallary_value but it didn't work for me

Comment: stop at the same step or at different step

Comment: did you got solution for this

Answer (score -2):

Backup or export below table

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value

truncate the table from both source and destination database and then run the migration.

after migration complete you can insert data in these tables.

Comment: why truncate catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table? we need source data into destination db

Comment: i have faced the same issue and i resolved it by doing above. if you have other solution please answer.

Comment: Yes, I solved this issue. Actually this issue due to some entity recorded in db, just replace magento 2 db with fresh installation db.

Comment: it works but after that how do I insert the data to M2 DB for catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table from M1 DB

Comment: @Jaisa from your backup of m1 table,you can add these data to m2 tables.